# client getting connections to multiple socket.io node.js servers

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am currently working on a project where one web page needs to connect to multiple socket.io node.js servers. How do I do this.

Comment: Not a good question at all. Please add more details and describe the exact problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating two socket.io instances?

```
var socket1 = io.connect('http://oneplace.com');
var socket2 = io.connect('http://anotherplace.com');
```