# Managing multiple socket.io servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to be able to programatically build, manage and close multiple Socket.io servers within the same Node.js application. I'm aware that I can hard code multiple servers into the code as shown in [client getting connections to multiple socket.io node.js servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647643/client-getting-connections-to-multiple-socket-io-node-js-servers), but I want to be able to add and remove them on the fly.

I have tried adding them into an array, but then the servers don't seem to run and nothing gets added to the array.

```
//main.js

const serverManager = require('./servers.js');

var activeServers = [];

var createServer = function(port) {
  var newServer = serverManager.build(port);
  activeServers.push(newServer);
  console.log(activeServers[0]) // Returns undefined
};

//servers.js

var socketio = require('socket.io');

exports.build = function(port) {
    var io = socketio.listen(port);
    return io;

//    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
//      console.log(socket.id + ' connected!')
//      socket.on('foo', function(msg1) {
//        socket.emit('bar','world');
//      });
//    });
  }
```

When I create a server using `createServer(portNumber)` (from main.js), the server runs fine and new connections are pushed to the console, but it doesn't seem to be added to the array. I am also unsure how to remove servers after they are added. I can add multiple servers on different ports and can connect to them all, but I'm unsure how to manage them or where they've been saved to after they've been created.

Comment: as i know you can use rooms for this propouse

Comment: well, you'r problem seems to be in the build function.. you'r not returning anything from it that's why you see blank object.. you need to `return io`;
But as mentioned in comment above, may be rooms will do the job ?

Comment: Why would you need an arbitrary number of socket.io servers all on different ports?  This sounds like a misunderstanding of how to solve some problem.  Please describe the actual problem you're trying to solve and we could probably offer you a better solution than what you're attempting.

Comment: Take a look at the native 'child_process' module in node. That will be your best friend, and is also great for hand-crafting your own "lite" version of pm2. Here is a good article providing some insight as to what im talking about:

http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Nodejs-managing-child-processes-starting-stopping-exec-spawn

Comment: var activeServers[]; syntax error. var activeServers = [];

Comment: @Pytth - It isn't clear why child_process would be needed here just to run multiple socket.io servers or why that has anything to do with the question being asked here.

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to be able to run servers on different interfaces, for example a server on 192.168.0.* to talk to machines on the local network and one on a public IP that can be connected to over the internet.

Comment: A single server can be reached both from the internet and from the LAN just fine.  You still haven't explained any reason why you would need an array of socket.io servers.

Comment: @jfriend00 Some computers on the LAN do not have internet connection and so would connect to the local IP address. Computers from the internet wouldn't be able to connect to the local IP address. I want to be able to spin up a new socket.io server for an arbitrary number of interfaces based on the layout of the network

Comment: That's still something that could be solved with networking and doesn't need an arbitrary number of servers.  But, I'll leave you to others I guess because I don't spend time on issues that I don't understand the need for.  Just trying to understand the real need for an arbitrary number of socket.io servers so I could offer the best advice.

Comment: @jfriend00 Or you could be a reasonable human being and offer a suggestion for how to implement multiple servers.

Comment: Well, I don't know what else you want.  You've already been told in the second comment here that your `build()` method doesn't return a value so `newServer` in `var newServer = new serverManager.build(port);` is just going to be `undefined` and thus you have an array of `undefined`.  What else are you waiting for?

Comment: @Maikal I modified it to return the io object but it still doesn't get added to the array

Comment: And, did you remove `new` from `var newServer = new serverManager.build(port);` because that doesn't seem to belong there either.

Comment: And, did you fix `var activeServers[];` to be valid Javascript?  Your question is full of mistakes, some of which you've been told about and you aren't giving us feedback on those mistakes.  It's hard for us to know what thread to follow here.  When you get a suggestion to fix a problem, you need to fairly quickly provide feedback on what exactly happened when you made that change and perhaps update your question to document what the remaining issues are.

Comment: @jfriend00 var activeServers[] was a typo in the question sorry. It obviously wouldn't have run if that was in my code like that. I've also removed the new keyword

Comment: @admrply - Please use the "edit" link below your question to FIX your typos.  We can't work on code full of typos that you say aren't the reason your code doesn't work.  I honestly don't know what your code looks like now since you've apparently applied several fixes already and still have a problem.  Can't work on code I can't see.  I'd suggest you fix all your typos.  Then, if you've applied some of the fixes and still have a problem, add a new copy of your code to your question with the fixes you have applied and then tell us what you observe is still the problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 I now get undefined as a result of printing the returned `io` object. I've updated the code to reflect my changes

Comment: What is `ios.listen(port);`?  Tracing back why you have `undefined` is elemental debugging that can be done by you with `console.log()` statements and/or breakpoints and a debugger.  You can do this hundreds of times faster yourself than we can guess what might be wrong.  I myself would set a breakpoint on the first line of the `build()` function and just step through it to see why I'm returning `undefined`.